# can't get rake spec to work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I'm following a tutorial to learn Ruby + Rails, and can't get rspec to work for me.

http://rubysource.com/rails-deep-dive-loccasions-home-page/

I am up to 'Our First Test', and when I run `rake spec` I get the following error:

```
harley-alexanders-macbook-pro:loccasions Harley$ rake spec
/Users/Harley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/acceptance/home_page_spec.rb
/Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require': cannot load such file -- rspec/capybara (LoadError)
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `block in require'
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:236:in `load_dependency'
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/activesupport-3.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:251:in `require'
    from /Users/Harley/Sites/rails/loccasions/spec/spec_helper.rb:6:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Harley/Sites/rails/loccasions/spec/acceptance/home_page_spec.rb:1:in `require'
    from /Users/Harley/Sites/rails/loccasions/spec/acceptance/home_page_spec.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load'
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `map'
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:746:in `load_spec_files'
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:69:in `run'
    from /Users/Harley/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@loccasions/gems/rspec-core-2.9.0/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:10:in `block in autorun'
rake aborted!
/Users/Harley/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/ruby -S rspec ./spec/acceptance/home_page_spec.rb failed

Tasks: TOP => spec
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

I found multiple times that the issue was outdated gems, but I've updated them all and my Gemfile to reflect this as well.

I know that 'feature' is a method of capybara- gem used for matching scenarios, etc. I'm including `require('rspec/capybara')` in my spec/spec_helber.rb file as well as having it in my Gemfile.

What am I doing wrong!?

Cheers,

~Harley

Answer (score 1):

Try instead:

```
bundle exec rake spec
```